# No video during boot between grub selection and X welcome

Tags: boot, nvidia

I'm running Ubuntu Bionic on a machine with a GTX 750 Ti (with nvidia driver) and no onboard video (there's a port on the motherboard, but my Xeon has no iGPU). When I installed Ubuntu I was using an HDMI cable from the GPU but I switched to DisplayPort when I got a new monitor.

Since switching video ports, I haven't had any video during boot, up until the X welcome / login screen, and sometimes a split second of text output appears prior to this. Setting `GRUB_MODE=terminal` in `/etc/default/grub` now displays the OS selection on screen, but after selecting Ubuntu the screen blanks.

Do I have to configure what video port to use for boot progress display?

Comment: Not sure but my first instinct would be to reinstall `grub` and see if it loads new video drivers. eg `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`